# Cordova Custom Camera Plugin - iOS Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm writing a Custom Camera Plugin for iOS and Android because the default one does not provide the functionality I need.

What I want to achieve is retrieving images from the camera in the background without displaying a preview screen/window so that they can be requested from the Javascript and used directly in the HTML or posted in Base64 by HTTP POST. (+ a few other things that are not ready yet :))

I've actually managed and I have uploaded my plugin here:
https://github.com/Moonware/cordova-cameraplus

Things are working as expected on Android but I have a problem on iOS (probably a memory leak).

It works for 3-4 minutes, the memory is increasing and suddently it stops refreshing (the app is still alive, the Camera object also).

Since ARC is enabled, I cannot manually release/dispose some of the objects myself. I have tried to wrap some places that were looking strategic with @autoreleasepool { }, memory usage is slightly better but the issue is still here.

I was wondering if there is an Objective C specialist out there who could have a look at my plugin and maybe provide some advises on how to fix this or at least locate where it comes from.

I have the feeling that it's the fact of calling the plugin every 50-100ms to retrieve an image that consumes the memory and doesn't release it (the returned string is between 8kb and 2Mb depending on the resolution of the camera):

```
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:base64String];

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

But even by stopping the refresh and the camera the memory never gets released even when CPU usages get lower.

In order to hopefully motivate somebody to have a look at the code, I have prepared a simple and ready-to-use Ionic project here:
https://github.com/Moonware/cordova-cameraplus-testapp

After grabbing this normally, all you have to do it:

```
cordova platform add ios (or android)
ionic build ios (or android)
```

Maybe there is a better approach. Suggestions are welcome anyway :)

I have realized (of course after creating my own) that I wasn't the first one with this idea but looking at the existing variants didn't help me to solve this problem.

The ones I've tried apparently have similar memory issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have exactly the same issue in our Cordova project (returning base64-encoded image repeatedly and displaying the image in the webview; eats memory and crashes after ~3 minutes). In one of my tests I made the calls at the same rate, but didn't set an image src with the datauri. No crash. This seems to suggest that the memory leak is actually in the Safari webview. Did you observe the same, or are you convinced that it is on the native side? (I've tried [this](http://www.fngtps.com/2010/mobile-safari-image-resource-limit-workaround/) to deal with the Safari GC issue but so far no luck.)

Comment: Have a look at the @autoreleasepool directive. We are chasing down zombie objects and this is helping. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html